# exception when deploying custom module in spring xd

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I have created my custom module to  read a stream file  format it  and write to rabbit mq

I   run below command to register module

```
module upload --type job --name messageca2 --file /Users/xyz/Downloads/spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE/xd/custom-modules/batch.jar
```

Successfully uploaded module 'job:messageca2'

then i am trying to create a job

```
job create --name messagerabbit2  --definition "messageca2 --makeUnique=false" --deploy
```

It says 
Successfully created and deployed job 'messagerabbit2'

But in log console i see below errors Please let me know if i miss something

```
group = 'messagerabbit2', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['makeUnique' -> 'false'], children = list[[empty]]]
2015-09-22T12:48:15-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Exception deploying module
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required module artifacts are either missing or invalid. Unable to determine module type for module definition: 'job:messageca2'.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createSimpleModule(ModuleFactory.java:122) ~[spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createAndConfigureModuleInstance(ModuleFactory.java:98) ~[spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:81) ~[spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.createModule(ModuleDeployer.java:181) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:363) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployJobModule(DeploymentListener.java:291) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
2015-09-22T12:48:15-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/9ceb7180-59b5-417b-a5fb-3dc546056bd3/messagerabbit2.job.messageca2.1, type=CHILD_REMOVED
2015-09-22T12:48:15-0500 1.2.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKJobDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for job 'messagerabbit2': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required module artifacts are either missing or invalid. Unable to determine module type for module definition: 'job:messageca2'.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createSimpleModule(ModuleFactory.java:122)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createAndConfigureModuleInstance(ModuleFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:81)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put your module in `/Users/xyz/Downloads/spring-xd-1.2.1.RELEASE/xd/custom-modules/` prior to uploading it with the `module upload` command, because this is actually exactly where it will **end up** being uploaded.

So given the error message, I'm pretty sure what's happening is the file ends up being corrupt because you're reading a file that you are currently recreating!

So, either upload it from somewhere else, or just put it there by hand and either

- generate an `.md5` hash for it by hand
- or disable the requirement for md5 checksums altogether, as seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/092c9e87278d78ef0923d6175a0f25a91b1d2505/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/application.yml#L87)